# access elements list for some values of a column

Tags: r, list

I have an object like

```
d1 <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"), y=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(name=c("A","C","D"), y=c(6,5,4))
d3 <- data.frame(name=c("B","C","E"), y=c(5,2,6))
my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)
```

I want to access (sum over) all elements of `y` corresponding to each of the entries in `name`.

That is, I aim for a result like the sum of the `y`s corresponding to `A` equal to 10, for `B` 10, too, `C` 11, `D` 4 and `E` 6. Each `name` may occur just once in total, or more than once. As the example is to indicate, they are neither at the same place in each `data.frame` nor is each `name` necessarily in each `data.frame` at all.

If necessary, I could supply the all the `name`s that occur in the list, but it would be even more convenient to generate it on the fly.

Comment: What about `name == E`, typo?

Comment: No, sorry, just to indicate that there are several letters. E may have been unnecessary to exhibit my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

(note that this works if you convert `name` `as.character`, not `as.factor`)

```
d1 <- data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"), y=c(4,5,6), stringsAsFactors = F)
d2 <- data.frame(name=c("A","C","D"), y=c(6,5,4), stringsAsFactors = F)
d3 <- data.frame(name=c("B","C","E"), y=c(5,2,6), stringsAsFactors = F)

my.list <- list(d1, d2, d3)


library(dplyr)
my.list %>% bind_rows() %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(sum_y = sum(y))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  name     sum_y
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 A           10
2 B           10
3 C           13
4 D            4
5 E            6
```

We can `bind_rows()` then simply `group_by()` names and `sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to use `do.call` in order to evaluate `rbind` before hand, and aggregate after

```
aggregate(y ~ name, do.call(rbind, my.list), sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Reduce`, `rbind` the dataframe and `aggregate` them by name

```
Reduce(function(x, y) aggregate(y~name, rbind(x, y), sum), my.list)

#  name  y
#1    A 10
#2    B 10
#3    C 13
#4    D  4
#5    E  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(my.list)[, .(sum_y = sum(y)), .(name)]
#   name sum_y
#1:    A    10
#2:    B    10
#3:    C    13
#4:    D     4
#5:    E     6
```